# Project design, many forms, many controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

I am implementing a project with a lot of forms and controls.   If I elect to dynamically create the popupforms for the user to specify options, what is the best way to fetch control specifics to save in a list or something, kill the form when the user is done specifying the particular options (for a task) and then load a form with options specific to what the user selected (before the form was killed).   Certainly VB.NET and MS developed a new way to strip everything from a form so this informaiton can be saved in RAM memory, and then apply that information whenever a form is instantiated via Dim myform as New Form(?)

In order to clarify what is being asked, I will enumerate several specific questions:

1. Which specific Visual Studio (VB.NET 2012) tool can best be implemented to minimize memory draw when dealing with numberous forms having hundreds of controls on each.  Possibly give code examples or pointers.
2. What specific mechanism exist in Visual Studio (VB.NET 2012) to serialize control data to either the registry or disk via e.g. streams to save data after an e.g. "Apply" button is selected, so that the particular GUI can undergo garbage collection ("GC").   When the controls are needed again, fetch their data that were last saved and populate the controls.
3. What has been proven to be the most effective (memory efficient) approach in Visual Studio (VB.NET 2012) for minimizing memory leaks consumed by GUI.

There seems to be some information pointing to the use of UserControls and XMLSerialize, however, there is sparse information on workflow needed to perform this explicitly.

Comment: I'm glad you provided more information, but this is still not a single real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically show different sets of options depending on the context, then I would recommend making a separate `UserControl` for each context.  Then, depending on the context, you could just add the appropriate user control(s) to your popup.  As far as data goes, I would strongly recommend that you separate the data model from the UI.  You should be layering your code in a way so that you are able to keep a copy of the data in memory without  having to keep a copy of the UI in memory.  In other words, you should be able to load and unload many instances of forms that all operate against the same copy of data in memory.  When you load a form or user control, you should simply give it a reference to the applicable data object(s) that it should display/maintain.

Comment: Strongly recommend all points here; we did an app with 900 unique panels that appeared in a workarea on most of the screen; the workarea was inside a main from with a left nav and menus and prev/next buttons. We separated the logic by subclassing the controls and using them for the forms (usercontrol/panels), and the subclassed implemented a 'getxml' and 'setxml' functions that would get and set their values to text. The main usercontrol inherited a control that looped thru, calling these. The business logic read/set the xml. From there on, google MVP. Hard, but it cut dev time in half.